# How to Inject application context from 'app' module to 'network' module using Koin DI

Tags: android, koin

I'm developing an application based on Koin DI (ver : 1.0.1) with 2 modules(:app and :network). I have a requirement in :network module to have "Context". Below is how I implemented:

```
**Module**:
val appModule = module {
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}

**Activity**:
private val viewModel by viewModel<LoginViewModel>()

**ViewModel**:
class LoginViewModel(val context: Context): ViewModel() {
  ...
  // Send "context" to network class in :network module
  ...
 }
```

Question: Is there any way we can directly send context to network class in :network module?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Both answers by @Rajat and @Andrey are correct. In fact if you look at the [sources](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/android/koin-android/src/main/java/org/koin/android/ext/koin/KoinExt.kt), you will see that `androidContext()` is just an extension function to `get()`, so these 2 definitions are identical:

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```

...

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(androidContext()) }
}
```

Answering your question, since `get()` and `androidContext()` are members of the `module` DSL object, you could do this:

```
val networkModule = module {
   single { Network(androidContext()) }
}
```

Or simply (I prefer this one for brevity):

```
val networkModule = module {
   single { Network(get()) }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Application context is available inside a module through the function [`androidContext()`](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/get-instances#using-the-android-context-in-a-definition).

Answer (score 8):

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(androidContext()) }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Other way to inject context is using Constructor DSL of Koin:

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::LoginViewModel)
}
```